# Docpad crash path.resolve

Tags: node.js, docpad

What causes the following error and how can it be fixed?

```
ESC[31merror:ESC[39m Something went wrong with the action
ESC[31merror:ESC[39m An error occured: 
TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
  at Object.exports.resolve (path.js:313:15)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:1406:36
  at Object.safeps.getHomePath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/safeps/out/lib/safeps.js:383:7)
  at Task.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:1401:25)
  at ambi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:55:18)
  at fire (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:373:25)
  at b (domain.js:183:18)
  at Domain.run (domain.js:123:23)
  at Task.fire (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:384:25)
  at Object._onImmediate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:400:26)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
ESC[31merror:ESC[39m To report the above error, follow the guide at: http://docpad.org/bug-report
ESC[32minfo:ESC[39m Shutting down... cya next time!
```

My docpad site is at https://github.com/robotbrain/gitio-site-docpad

Comment: A few more details might be helpful. Copying and pasting the error message into the question is a good starting point. The error comes from one of the core node modules, Path (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path). This sort of error often happens when you pass an undefined string to Path.resolve etc. But without having a bit more information its hard to work out what's happening in your case.

Comment: The error, according to the stacktrace, occurs in docpad. The server is being run by an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by setting HOME and using setuid in the upstart script